# how to open a other window in C# MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a simple problem:
In my application i have a "mainview" / Mainwindow.
From this the user can controll all the things like DB querys, searching and so on.

But i need to open a property window on a click on the menuebutton.

So i bound it to my **SearchWindowCommand**:

```
private ICommand searchwindowcommand;

       public ICommand SearchWindowCommand
       {
           get
           {
               if (searchwindowcommand == null)
               {
                   searchwindowcommand = new RelayCommand(p => ExcecuteSearchwindowcommand());
               }
               return searchwindowcommand;
           }
       }

       public void ExcecuteSearchwindowcommand()
       {


       }
```

Usualy i would open it like this: (i had the application working, but i didnt used mvvm and now i have to redo the application and figure mvvm out :) )

```
 public void auswahl_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Einstellungen suchwindow = new Einstellungen();
            app_config_load(suchwindow);
            suchwindow.Show();

        }
```

What do i have to write into my Executecommand to show up the other window?
And should i create  a new viewmodel for the other view? (i guess yes?)

Edit:
My Startapplikationcode:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window

{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetupBindings();
    }

    private void SetupBindings()
    {
        pViewModelList viewModel = new pViewModelList();

        personlistview.DataContext = viewModel;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> And should i create a new viewmodel for the other view? (i guess yes?)

Yes.

> What do i have to write into my Executecommand to show up the other
>   window?

What I usually do in this case is, I raise an event in the ViewModel. The view attaches a handler to this event, and the actual `ShowDialog()` is executed in this handler.

Here's some pseudo code that shows the idea:

```
// ViewModel
public class MainViewModel
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs<UpdateViewModel>> UpdateRequested;

    private void ExecuteUpdate()
    {
        if (this.UpdateRequested != null)
        {
            var childVm = new UpdateViewModel(/* parameters related to the object being updated */);
            this.UpdateRequested(this, new EventArgs<UpdateViewModel>(childVm));
        }
    }
}

// View
public class MainView
{
    public MainView()
    {
        var vm = new MainViewModel();
        this.DataContext = vm;

        vm.UpdateRequested += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var updateView = new UpdateView();
            updateView.DataContext = e.Data;    // Gets the instance of the viewModel here

            updateView.ShowDialog();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with the event, but I think that a new ViewModel is not mandatory. That depend on the purpose of the new window.

Comment: Hi!
The problem is, that i cant make a reference to the startapplikation, because the startapplikation already refer to my viewmodel (for the context?!)
Now i dont know how i can make a instance of the other window clase to use ShowDialog()

Edit: The purpose is just to set some stuff in the appconfig, nothing special.

Comment: @Xaruth Indeed it's not mandatory. But I personally always create a viewModel per view if the view needs bindings. Just a personal preference so it's more clear for the person who reads the code to associate the view and its viewModel

Comment: @user3793935 The main rule of MVVM is: **views have references to the viewModels but viewModels don't reference the views**. I don't know about your startapplikation (maybe provide more code in the question), but in any case the viewModel must not reference the view.

Comment: Uff, sorry, im a little bit confused.

I provide the startapplikation code in the question(its just the databinding ... thought i can do the same with the other window and then somehow call it with my ExcecuteCommand)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not essential to create new viewmodel for each view. But you should create a new one in your case. To open a new window from your viewmodel, Use the mediator pattern such as MVVM Light's Messenger service.

In your ViewModel:

```
Messenger.Default.Send(ViewName.PropertyWindow);
```

MainWindow.cs

```
Messenger.Default.Register<ViewName>(this, ShowPropertyWindow);

private void ShowPropertyWindow(ViewName view)
{
  if(view == ViewName.PropertyWindow)
  {
    var propertyWindow = new PropertyWindow();
    propertyWindow.DataContext = new PropertyWindowViewModel();
    propertyWindow.Show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I currently have a requirement for something similar, the user wants to be open a report in another window.

I've done this (in MVVM) by using a 'wrapper' class around the actual instance of the Window class, importantly the wrapper constructor is passed an interface to a ViewModel which the Window is going to render. The wrapper has methods for 'Show', 'Close' etc which hide the actual Window implementation class.

The instances of the wrapper class are created & tracked by a service class which knows about all open windows and has the ability to close all windows when the app closes or the user choose to close them from another ViewModel.

Hope that makes sense!

View class:

```
 public partial class TearOffWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        public TearOffWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SourceInitialized += (s, a) => this.HideMinimizeButtons();
        }
    }
```

Wrapper implementation:

```
public sealed class TearOffWindowWrapper : IWindowWrapper<TearOffWindow>
    {
        private readonly TearOffWindow _window;

        public TearOffWindowWrapper(ITearOffViewModel viewModel)
        {
            _window = new TearOffWindow { DataContext = viewModel };
        }

        public event EventHandler Closed;

        public bool IsVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return _window.Visibility == Visibility.Visible;
            }

            set
            {
                _window.Visibility = value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            _window.Close();
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            if (!_window.IsVisible)
            {
                _window.Closed += WindowOnClosed;

                _window.Show();
                _window.Activate();
            }
        }

        public void Activate()
        {
            if (_window.IsVisible)
            {
                _window.Activate();
            }
        }

        private void WindowOnClosed(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            _window.Closed -= WindowOnClosed;

            var closed = Closed;
            if (closed != null)
            {
                closed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I pass in an interface called `ITearOffViewModel`, this contains the Title and Contents for the Window, which are bound to the DataTemplate for the View in the standard WPF\MVVM way.

```
public interface ITearOffViewModel : IViewModel
    {
        string Title { get; }

        IViewModel Content { get; }
    }
```

Comment: Hui, thats alot of code just for opening a window ;(
Ill try it out, hopefully it works :)

Answer (score 0):

### Should i create a new viewmodel for the other view? (i guess yes?)

this depends on your Viewmodel and what you are trying to do with it

let's say you have a `List<Person>` displayed so the user where can select a Person and edit this person. Sure you need a VM for this model but if it is a `List<PersonVM>` there would be no need to to create a new `PersonVM` just for editing because your VM should be able to handle such things.

### How to show up the other window?

This is just an simple example which surely violate the rule of loss coupling a bit becaus it know's there is view but it doesn't know PersonV because PersonV is a Usercontrol

```
   public void ExcecuteSearchwindowcommand()
   {
       var vm = //if you need to select a VM or create a new VM

       var v = new view(vm) // view is a modified Window

       v.ShowDialog()

      if(vm.Result)// Result will be an property which tells you
      {            // how the user closed the Window e.g. Save,Cancel, ...
      }
      //else or whatever

   }
```

view.cs

```
    // this are my constructors

    // obj is your vm
    public DetailV(object obj)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = obj;
        CPresenter.Content = obj;

        initializeCostumComponent();
    }

    // dataContext is your vm and 
    // content is an Usercontrol
    public DetailV(object dataContext, object content)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = dataContext;
        CPresenter.Content = content;

        initializeCostumComponent();
    }
```

view.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="view"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Top="150"
        DataContext="{Binding ElementName=CPresenter,Path=Content}"
        Title="{Binding DisplayTitle}" Loaded="Window_Loaded" TabIndex="99999999">
    <ScrollViewer Name="viewer"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ScrollContentPresenter Name="CPresenter" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

now to tell the default view for an specific vm i use an ResourceDictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

                     xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:NamespaceViewModel"
                     xmlns:vw="clr-namespace:NamespaceView">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PersonVM}">
        <vw:PersonV  />
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And if you now have an AdressVM just add it to your ResourceDictionary and it works